# (Magento 1.9) Change boxes of advanced search from list (each under the other) to side-by-side boxes

Tags: magento, search

in Magento advanced search the boxes where you can type in search words for attributes like "SKU", "Manufacturer", "Material" etc. are in a list, each box is among each other.

I want to have the boxes side by side (parallel to each other) and the "search" button also in that line.

Does anybody have an idea how to do that? It should not be difficult, I just cant find a way to do it :(

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution. If somebody is interested:

.advanced-search li { float:left; }

so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

simply use float:left

```
.form-list > li {
    float: left;
}
```